# Django UpdateView can edit user who created and user to whom record is assigned

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Let's say I have model like

```py
class Record(models.Model):
  created = ......
  assigned = .......
  some_other_fields = .....
```

How should I modify `test_func()` in views to allow edit `Record` both to creator and user to whom the `Record` is assigned? I would like to enable functionality in frontend side, not in the django admin panel. I'm working with Class Based Views.

Standard `test_func` in `UpdateView` looks like:

```py
def test_func(self):
  return self.request.user == self.object.created
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code, based on @enes-islam answer:

```py
def test_func(self):
     if self.request.user == self.object.created or self.request.user == self.object.assigned:
             return True
      return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def test_func(self):
  return self.request.user == self.object.created == self.object.assigned
```

Or:

```
def test_func(self):
     if self.request.user == self.object.created:
         if self.request.user == self.object.assigned:
             return True
      return False
```

Comment: A little bit modified version solved my problem (code below).

Comment: nice to see that